# Using ressources for html with rest server

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

Im trying to create a website using java REST server. To be able to load premade html files i need to know WHERE they are being saved on my server. I coudltn find anything about that topic on google or whereever, so either im blind or the answer is too easy to be mentioned somewhere :D

So yeah, im deploying my .war file on an external jersey rest server and i would like to be able to load files that are attached to that .war-file (included in eclipse project in the folder WEB-INF). How do i access those?!

Thank you in advance, once again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the resources are JSP's, you can do something like the following:

```java
@GET
public void getHome(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        ...
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "There was an error getting the ...", e);
    }
}
```

If the resource is a image:

```
@GET
@Path("/get/{name}")
@Produces("image/png")
public Response getFile(@Context ServletContext context, @PathParam("name") String name) {

    String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/images/" + name);
    File file = new File(fullPath);

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    return response.build();

}
```

etc.